# vuejs and axios cannot download file .xls after request to url

Tags: vue.js, axios

I got a problem when I need to download .xls file using axios and vuejs.

My code is after user press the button, it will call API with authorise header then API return response with attached file (.xls).

This is my download function

```
download(url, data = null, options = {}) {

        let vuex = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('vuex'))
        let accessToken = vuex.Auth.accessToken
        let header = {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
        return http
            .post(url, data, {
                ...options,
                headers: {
                    ...header,
                    ...options.headers
                },
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            })
            .then(res => res.data)
            .then(data => {
                let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' })
                let link = document.createElement('a')
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                link.download = 'Report.xls'
                link.click()

            })
    },
```

it return some data like ...
[image]

But I cannot download the file because I got `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

What's wrong on my code.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of dev tools network tab. Include the complete include everything under General, Response Headers, and Request Headers.

Comment: You need to actually insert the element into the DOM. `document.body.appendChild(a)`. [Here is a popular library](https://github.com/dtjohnson/xlsx-populate#browser-usage) that does exactly this and it works fine.

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com

this is response header i got

cache-control: cache, must-revalidate
cf-ray: 4e1669627bfbc8eb-BKK
content-disposition: attachment; filename="Order Report.xls"
content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 04 Jun 2019 02:17:39 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 04 Jun 2019 09:17:39
pragma: public
server: cloudflare
status: 200
vary: Authorization